# How to Access This.props.route.params in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, class, react-native-flatlist

my first page pushing an array with some data to next page ,I want to use that data in RenderItem for flatlist.I tried bind event but its also not worked for me ,any help would be appriciated.

```
 export default class mainPage extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      slots: [],
      screen: 'screen1',
      vehicleNumber: '',
      parkingLot: [],
      selectedSlot: '',
    }
  }

  createSlot() {
    let tempdata: any[] = []
    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(this.state.text); i++) {
      tempdata.push({
        allocated: false,
        timestamp: new Date(),
      })
    }
    this.setState(
      {
        slots: [
          ...this.state.slots,
          {
            id: (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7),
            count: parseInt(this.state.text),
            data: tempdata,
          },
        ],
        text: '',
        screen: 'screen2',
      },
      () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('floor', {
          slots: this.state.slots,
        })
      },
    )
  }
  // componentDidMount() {

  //   this.setState({ parkingLot: [...this.parkingLot] })

  // }
  park = () => {
    console.log('jcjhj', this.state.parkingLot)
    var item = this.state.slots[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.slots.length)
    ]
    console.log('Parkinglot', this.state.parkingLot, item)
    console.log('Slots', this.state.slots)
    if (this.state.slots) {
    }

    // this.setState({
    //   parkingLot: [
    //     ...this.state.parkingLot,
    //     { carnumber: this.state.vehicleNumber },
    //   ],
    // })
  }
  renderItem(item: any) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.Slotinput}
        onPress={() =>
          this.setState({ screen: 'screen3', selectedSlot: item.id })
        }
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Slot ID:-{item.id}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Slot Count:-{item.count}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  renderItem1(item: any) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.Slotinput}>
        <Text>{item.allocated ? 'Allocated' : 'Available'}</Text>
        {this.state.parkingLot.map((e: any) => {
          return <Text>{e.carnumber}</Text>
        })}
      </View>
    )
    //   )
    // }
    // return demo
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.screen === 'screen1' && (
          <View style={styles.form}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="Enter A value for slot"
              onChangeText={(text: any) => this.setState({ text })}
              value={this.state.text}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={
                this.state.text && this.state.text
                  ? styles.addItemButton
                  : styles.BlurItemButton
              }
              disabled={this.state.text == ''}
              onPress={() => this.createSlot()}
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
        {/* {this.state.screen === 'screen2' && (
          <>
            <Text onPress={() => this.setState({ screen: 'screen1' })}>
              Back
            </Text>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.slots}
              renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item)}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
          </>
        )} */}
        {/* {this.state.screen === 'screen3' && (
          <>
            <Text onPress={() => this.setState({ screen: 'screen2' })}>
              Back
            </Text>
            <>
              {}
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Vechicle Number"
                style={styles.input}
                value={this.state.vehicleNumber}
                onChangeText={(vehicleNumber: any) =>
                  this.setState({ vehicleNumber })
                }
                // onChangeText={data => this.setState({ vehicleNumber: data })}
              ></TextInput>
            </>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.addItemButton}
              onPress={() => this.park()}
            >
              <Text>Park Vechicle</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            {this.state.slots
              ?.filter((i: any) => i.id === this.state.selectedSlot)
              ?.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                return (
                  <View key={index}>
                    <FlatList
                      data={item.data}
                      renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem1(item)}
                      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    />
                  </View>
                )
              })}
          </>
        )} */}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my floor.tsx page(next page)

```
export default class floor extends Component<any, any> {
  handleslot: any
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    // console.log('SLOTDATA::--', props.route.params)
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      slots: [],
      screen: 'screen1',

      selectedSlot: '',
    }
    // let slo: Array<any> = this.props.route.params
    // console.log('propdata-->', slo)
    // this.setState({
    //   slo: [],
    // })
  }

  renderItem=(item: any)=> {
    console.log('item', item)

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.Slotinput}
        onPress={() =>
          this.setState({ screen: 'screen3', selectedSlot: item.id })
        }
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Slot ID:-{item.id}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Slot Count:-{item.count}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>Back</Text>

        <FlatList
          data={this.props.route.params}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
          this.renderItem(item)}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: whats props.route.params printing? there must be another variable name right? this.props.route.params.slots ?

Comment: yes..its props.route.params.slots

Comment: did that solve the issue?

Comment: yesssss....i put the while in Data={} in flat list

Comment: Ok, then ill add it as an answer.

Comment: {id: '7vkh6j', count: 2, data: Array(2)}

Comment: {id: '7vkh6j', count: 2, data: Array(2)} i want to access this data array on third page i sent props like  onPress={() =>
          this.setState(
            this.props.navigation.navigate('parkingSlot', {
              space: this.props.route.params.slots,
            })

Comment: Same way, **this.props.route.params.space**.

Comment: Property 'route' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.    getting this line after insert into data={}

Comment: Can you share your parkingSlot code? Looks like you have not taken props data in your 3rd screen.

Comment: export default class parkingSlot extends Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    console.log('parkingSlots::--', props.route.params)

    this.state = {
      text: '',
      parkingLots: props.route.params,
      screen: 'screen1',
      selectedSlot: '',
    }
  }
  renderItem = (item: any) => {
    console.log('Data', item.item.data)

Comment: return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.Slotinput}
        // onPress={() =>
        //   this.setState(
        //     this.props.navigation.navigate('parkingSlot', {
        //       space: this.props.route.params.slots,
        //     }),
        //   )
        // }
      >
       </TouchableOpacity>  )}
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
  <FlatList
          data={this.props.route.params.space}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

Comment: Can you try with Component<any, any>?

Comment: yes i tried sir,

Comment: 129 757 995 anydesk Id please help me sir in this code

Comment: sir got the solution finally ... now i want insert value of textinput in that array

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are not selecting the proper data to pass in the flatlist.
**this.props.route.params.slots** will give you the slots you are passing from previous screen. Try this

```
  <FlatList
          data={this.props.route.params.slots}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
          this.renderItem(item)}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
```